# Returning list of object as a json result

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am returning List of object from c# to javascript using Json , my code is:

**c#**

```
 List<GuestRSVP_Info> Ser_Result = new List<GuestRSVP_Info>(); 
 return Json(test, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**javascript**

```
$.post("url", { }, function(){alert("success");}).error(function(){ alert("error");});
```

I always got `error alert`, but if i send only 1 object instead of list i got `success alert`.Whats the problem here?

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but I'm pretty sure you need to make a dictionary of the list with key -> value pairs before you can make it a valid JSON object with `return Json`

Comment: Did you try navigating directly to the url in your browser? What error did you get when you tried this?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy List can be normally converted to valid jsons. Although I don't know what's happening in that particular case (I'm not a C# developer as well). Tom, instead of alerting "error" why don't you inspect the actuall error in console??

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because you sending JSON object using POST. In POST we sending ONE json object every timne. When want to send array, list ... or some othere object, he need to be send as JSON.

```
var data = {
   myArrayOfObjects : [
        { name : 'name 1', value : 'value 1'},
        { name : 'name 2', value : 'value 2'}
        ....
    ],
   secondParameter : { 
    ...
   },
   lastParameter: true
};
```